# system class(System.Web.UI.Page) property(httpresponse) equivalent in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

I am reproducing a set of code from webform to mvc.
I have a code in webform in which,

**Webform(aspx.cs):**

```
FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInResponse(responseMessage, Response);
```

where **Response** is a property of System.Web.Ui.Page class. I am not sure whether we can use it in MVC controller code since it is a page class.

What i have tried?

1.I  tried creating an object of System.Web.Ui.Page class and passed object.Response.
When i execute the code in controller it throws null.

2.I Created a property of httpResponse class (System.Web.HttpResponse) and passed it as argument in the above method.
It throws null.

Is there any equivalent class property to System.Web.Ui.Page 's Response property that i can use  for ProcessSignInResponse() of Microsoft.IdentityModel.FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations in MVC?

Answer (score 1):

You can use static property  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response

Answer (score 0):

It dragged too much of time to find though it is an easy fix.

I used **System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response** as the attribute in place of property Response(System.Web.Ui.Page).

**C#(in Controller):**

```
FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInResponse(responseMessage, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response );
```